# How to install openssl 1.1.1 in ubuntu for ARM cross compilation

Tags: arm, openssl, cross-compilation

I have build script for ARM cross compilation and is running on x86 machine. This script has commands as below.

`sudo debootstrap --arch=amd64 --variant=buildd focal /srv/armRoot"`

`echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe" >  /etc/apt/sources.list`

`echo "deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main universe" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list`

`echo "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list`

`sudo apt-get install -y openssl:armhf`

`sudo apt-get install -y  libssl-dev:armhf`

But these commands are installing openssl `3.0.2-0ubuntu1`. But my requirement is openssl 1.1.1 version

What changes are needed in above commands to install 1.1.1 instead of 3.0.2 version of openssl?

Ubuntu version is 20.04(Focal)

Comment: Please provide OS & release details; package versions vary on release, and you've not told us yours.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openssl&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all indicates it's possibly *jammy* but it's better if we're told instead of guessing & potentially suggesting inappropriate fixes for you based on assumption.

Comment: Ubuntu version is 20.04(Focal)

Comment: The version I'd expect (see my first comment) for *focal* or 20.04 is `1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x` and not what you state.  I'd suggest running `sudo apt update` and check what you're actually running, and what you have in your sources as `3.0.2-0ubuntu1.7: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x ` is the *jammy* package!!  (see first comment link)

Comment: Yes, I understood for focal  it shud be 1.1.1f. But am getting 3.0.2. Not sure how !? Pls refer to edited question above for list of all commands used

Comment: Please add the output of `apt policy openssl` to your question. This will show what software source you have added to your system that is providing the newer version of the package.

Comment: This is the output while executing my script `openssl:armhf is already the newest version (3.0.2-0ubuntu1).`

Comment: That isn't the output of `apt policy openssl` Please run the requested command and paste the output into your question, not into a comment.

Comment: You're either not using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (maybe a non-Ubuntu OS based on Ubuntu 20.04 for example) **or** you've polluted your sources with non-Ubuntu or non-focal sources which `apt-cache policy openssl` or `apt policy openssl` would possibly show, thus the request for it to be added to your question.

Comment: As informed earlier, This is ARM cross compilation on x86 machine. This is done by Seting ARM architecture in 'dpkg' & Installing all dependent packages. Once script runs completely, it deleted all the temp folders created for compilation. So not possible to run `apt policy openssl`